# Matrix = Matrix.rowwise().reverse() Eigen rowwise reverse a matrix and assign it back makes each row symmetric

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

Simple question, but cannot figure why:

**Input**

```
Eigen::MatrixXd Ha(2, 3);
Ha << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6;
std::cout << "Ha: " << std::endl << Ha << std::endl;

Ha.rowwise().reverse();
std::cout << "Ha: " << std::endl << Ha.rowwise().reverse() << std::endl;

Ha = Ha.rowwise().reverse();
std::cout << "Ha: " << std::endl << Ha.rowwise().reverse() << std::endl;
```

**Output**

```
Ha:
1 2 3
4 5 6
Ha:
3 2 1
6 5 4
Ha:
3 2 3
6 5 6
```

For the last one, why is the case?

Answer (score 5):

Well, I finally figured out.
This is because Eigen use lazy evaluation and we need to override the lazy evaluation of elementwise operation.

So this works:

```
Ha = Ha.rowwise().reverse().eval();
```

This is called "Aliasing" in Eigen's wiki:

https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicAliasing.html

Comment: For performance reasons I get it. But for developing, oh my lord that is SO nasty. THANKYOU.